Quarkus hibernate orm make a many to many relationship
I have three classes :
VoteProposition
Proposition
VoteProposition_Proposition
VoteProposition
@Entity
@Table(name = "voteproposition")
public class VoteProposition  implements Serializable {

    public Long id;

    // List of Propositions
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "voteproposition_proposition",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "voteproposition_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "proposition_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    public List<Proposition> propositions;





    public VoteProposition() {

    }

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "votepropositionSeq", sequenceName = "voteproposition_id_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "votepropositionSeq")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

Proposition
@Entity
@Table(name = "proposition")
public class Proposition implements Serializable {



    public Long id;
    public  int position;

    public  String text;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "voteproposition_proposition",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "voteproposition_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "proposition_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    public List<VoteProposition> votePropositions;




    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "propositionSeq", sequenceName = "proposition_id_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "propositionSeq")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

and the liaison one
VoteProposition_Proposition
@Embeddable
@Table(name = "voteproposition_proposition")
public class VoteProposition_Proposition implements Serializable {


        @Column(name = "voteproposition_id")
        protected Long votePropositionId;

        @Column(name = "proposition_id")
        protected Long propotionId;
    }

but i have a :

hibernate.MappingException: Error creating SQL 'create' commands for
table 'proposition' [Unable to determine SQL type name for column
'votePropositions' of table 'proposition': class
org.hibernate.type.internal.BasicTypeImpl cannot be cast to class
org.hibernate.type.BasicPluralType
(org.hibernate.type.internal.BasicTypeImpl and
org.hibernate.type.BasicPluralType are in unnamed module of loader
io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @279ad2e3)]

How to make properly a many to many relationship in my case ?
Regards

can you please see if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77016212/manytomany-relationship-with-composite-primary-key-in-quarkus-hibernate.    He has done it in a different way :)
